# (codeigniter ajax) dont want to save data

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

i have trouble in ajax function.. 
in case, i want to inserting data from clicking anchor-button named "tambah_tmp"..
im not really understand with ajax, from started i have read suggestion from internet "how to load data from ajax" and now im trying to saving/inserting data with that method by myself but still doesnt work, here the code:

AJAX

```
function tampil_buku_cari()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: 'ajax',
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>pinjambuku/daftar_buku",
    async: 'false',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      var html = '';
      var i;
      for (i=0; i<data.length; i++)
      {
        html+=  '<tr>'+
                '<td id="cari_isbn">'+data[i].buku_isbn+'</td>'+
                '<td id="cari_nama">'+data[i].buku_nama+'</td>'+
                '<td id="cari_penulis">'+data[i].buku_penulis+'</td>'+
                '<td><a class="btn btn-primary" id="tambah_tmp" isbn="'+data[i].buku_isbn+'" nama="'+data[i].buku_nama+'" penulis="'+data[i].buku_penulis+'"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a></td>'+
                '</tr>';
      } 
      $('#daftar_cari').html(html);
    }
  });
}

 $("#tambah_tmp").click(function(){ 
  var tmp_isbn = $("#cari_isbn").val();
  var tmp_nama = $("#cari_nama").val();
  var tmp_penulis = $("#cari_penulis").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>pinjambuku/input_for_tmp",
    type: "POST",
    data: "cari_isbn="+tmp_isbn+"&cari_nama="+tmp_nama+"&cari_penulis="+tmp_penulis,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
      alert('Input sukses');
    }
  });
  $("#cari_buku").modal("hide"); });
```

MODEL :

```
function input_tmp($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('td_tmp', $data);

}
```

CONTROLLER :

```
public function input_for_tmp()
{
    $isbn = $this->input->post('cari_isbn');
    $nama = $this->input->post('cari_nama');
    $penulis = $this->input->post('cari_penulis');


    $data = array(
        'buku_isbn' => $isbn,
        'buku_nama' => $nama,
        'buku_penulis' => $penulis
    );

    $proc = $this->M_pinjambuku->input_tmp($data);

}
```

sorry if u have misunderstanding, my english not really good and i still have learning

Comment: type will be either GET or POST not ajax

Comment: add `print_r($_POST)` in `input_for_tmp`: what is it showing? also `type: 'ajax'` isn't valid should be either get or post.... also *define* or *explain* what **exactly** isn't working

Comment: ok i have change "ajax" into "POST" .. and im trying to open from localhost/folder_name/my_controller/input_for_tmp , then the result says my column "buku_isbn" is NULL.. but i have already declaration on function tampil_buku_cari()??

Comment: "add print_r($_POST) in input_for_tmp: what is it showing?" ... you can view the response in the network tab of chrome for the request

Comment: i already add print_r... when i click the anchor-button **tambah_tmp** not showing anything in network, and the modal still showing cant be hide

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors which i have encountered in there.

Firstly in your `tampil_buku_cari()` function, replace `type: 'ajax'` with `type: 'GET'`

Secondly, while passing data in the lower ajax function, there will be a little edit. 
replace the data field from `data: "cari_isbn="+tmp_isbn+"&cari_nama="+tmp_nama+"&cari_penulis="+tmp_penulis` to `data: {"cari_isbn": tmp_isbn, "cari_nama": tmp_nama, "cari_penulis": tmp_penulis}`

Thirdly `print_r($proc);` after declaring $proc array.

Comment: l already change as u said.. but when i try open localhost/my_folder/my_controller/input_for_tmp and it says the value is NULL?? how can it be? i already declaration the value in the lower ajax function `INSERT INTO td_tmp (buku_isbn, buku_nama, buku_penulis) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL)`

Comment: still doesnt work... and i think the button might be doesnt work, because the modal still showing not change to hide

Answer (score 0):

now i have try to change
`<td><a class="btn btn-primary" id="tambah_tmp" isbn="'+data[i].buku_isbn+'" nama="'+data[i].buku_nama+'" penulis="'+data[i].buku_penulis+'"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a></td>`
INTO this :
`<td><a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="tmp_input()" id="tambah_tmp" href="#"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a></td>`

now i caught some error and said **Uncaught ReferenceError: tmp_input is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (pinjambuku:)**